# Is it possible to style the new Facebook Page Plugin?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-likebox

The Facebook Like Box for Pages is being deprecated today, and Facebook is encouraging Page owners to replace it with the new Page Plugin.  I have not been able to style the new Page Plugin though, and the white background does not look good on sites with dark backgrounds.

Here is what the Page Plugin code looks like:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com" data-width="500"
data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false"
data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com"><a href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
</blockquote>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried inserting `style="background-color:black !important;"` in both of the divs, but the plugin background color remains white.

Has anyone been able to style the Page Plugin successfully?

Comment: The options you have for styling the plugin are the ones listed on the documentation page. And of course giving the div elements a background doesn’t help, because the document displayed inside the iframe does specify its own background color.

Answer (score 2):

In their current implementation, Facebook doesn't allow you to change the background color from white. The full list of attributes that they do allow are on their [developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#settings).